# cannot drag custom imageview using ontouchlistener

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

i'm new to android programming... i'm trying to move a newly created imageview that is added to layout using gesture(specifically, ontouchlistener).. it managed to add the imageview, but the ontouchlistener only catch until ACTION_DOWN.. here is my code :

```
package com.calengine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class coba extends CALEngineActivity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

    private ImageView movableimage;
    private FrameLayout layout;
    private LayoutParams params;
    int status;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainform2);

        layout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.absLayoutAction);
        status = 0;
            movableimage = new ImageView(this);
            movableimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_launcher);
            layout.addView(movableimage);
            movableimage.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) movableimage.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
            txt.setText("Created");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            txt.setText("Moving");
            int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
            int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

            layoutParams.leftMargins = x_cord - 25;
            layoutParams.topMargins = y_cord - 75;

            movableimage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            txt.setText("Up");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I assume for those events the textview will show corresponding texts.. But it only show "Created", no "Moving" or "Up"... the image won't move either... how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return true in onTouch method.

Comment: thanks, it finally works!! in my previous attempts i already gave return true, but it just didn't works... Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you return false out of a listener, it stops giving you more info (relating to the subsequent events that are coming through).  Try returning true and see if that fixes your problem. Offhand I don't see anything else that's fundamentally wrong (though a long lecture is in order on the *correct way to do what you're doing here, which doesn't involve AbsoluteLayout, but rather a SurfaceView onto which you can draw (and manipulate) whatever you wish... but that is a tad more advanced.

here's a reasonably simple start. Keep in mind that you can capture touch events on any view, and in this example you would just add that feature to draw whatever you wish to the relevant coordinates. You can easily find tutorials on how to drag stuff around.
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html

Comment: thanks.. I have tried to find more about surfaceview, but i thought i needed more time to study it and the time just wasn't enough (i'm doing this for a simple project). in the future, im gonna try to use surfaceview and custom views more... thanks for your suggestion :)